# How can I open a file in another app using UIDocumentInteractionController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uidocumentinteraction

I'm having trouble trying to open a file.

I download a document file somewhere, and I have a viewer to view the file on my iPhone. I want my app to open the file to the viewer.

Here's what I'm trying to do in `-(IBAction)buttonPressed`:

```
dc = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
if([dc presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES])
{
   NSLog(@"menu is presented");
}
```

When I run the program and click trigger `buttonPressed`, the `NSLog` message is printed, and an action sheet appears with two options. One is evernote, the other one is viewer.

However, when I click either option in the action sheet popup, nothing happens.

What am I missing? Do I need to implement a delegate method?

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try the code if yes then please put your code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've got the answer.

i must retain dc..

fool mistake :(

Comment: You can accept your own answer. You might want to add your corrected code to it first though.

Comment: Thank you, another fool made the same mistake

Comment: @dariru you can set dc as property. @property(nonatomic, retain) UIDocumentInteractionController *dc;

or you can retain manually like this.
dc = [[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url] retain];

notice.
if you retain it with property or manually, you have to release it somewhere. but if you're using ARC, you don't need to do that. compiler will insert release code for you. the code above based on you're using MRC.